# Java's DatagramSocket not receiving packets (in production only)

Tags: java, udp

First of all, it works locally. The issue happens only when I upload my code to Heroku. I can see in my logs that the server is working fine, and it's simply not receiving socket data through UDP.
Creating the socket:

```
DatagramSocket socket;
try {
    socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error(e.toString());
}
```

Listening for packets:

```
try {
    byte[] data = new byte[256];
    DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
    socket.receive(receivePacket);
    logger.log("Got packet!"); // This is never reached
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.log(e.toString());
}
```

I tried connecting to the server (through mac) by running netstat: `nc -u garbil.herokuapp.com 40791`, but it simply doesn't work.

The server logs can be viewed in http://garbil.herokuapp.com/logs.

Comment: many hosting environments disable udp/multicast (i know AWS does).  why are you using udp instead of tcp?

Answer (score 1):

Well i guess this is a firewall issue :)

You need to check that you configured well the "PORT" var :
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#web-dynos

Then you also might have to check that the provider allow you to use UDP...